# Meteor: choose custom javascript and custom css for template

Tags: javascript, css, meteor

AFAIK, in Meteor, when compiling app, all javascript files and all css files will be merged to one file. I think this behavior will slow down app (because user must download all css and javascript that unnecessary for that page). Moreover, this behavior makes our app not dynamic, because maybe some page, we need different css or javascript files.

So my question is: How can we choose custom javascript and custom css for a template ? Does Meteor support this ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Meteor is not supporting this exactly in that way. So you are left with two workarounds.
 One would be writing a own extension which helps you in that regard or finding one which already exists.
 And the other would be putting your special resources somewhere in the `/yourMeteorApp/public` folder which is excluded from the merge process (see http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp). And now you could write some template specific logic to load and evaluate JS and CSS resources from there when your template is accessed. Resources in `public` are available directly on root level - so `public/js/my.js` would be available under `www.example.com/js/my.js`.

**UPDATE:**
This answer is quite old and in modern Meteor apps you should make use of the import logic (and the `imports` folder) which didn't exist in that way when I originally answered this: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#intro-to-import-export
This should be the best way to handle any dynamic JS requirements and strucutre an app by far nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

In practice this has yet to be a problem for me. The combined javascript files are minified and obfuscated. The fact that any "page load" within the UI is done without a server GET makes the UI quite snappy. I have over 20 packages which add up to 2.1MB of js loading when the app cold-starts. Even on iOS it feels fast.